# Anchor links not working

Tags: 8

I am using Drupal 8 and my same page anchors aren't working. I am using the Glazed visual builder by Sooperthemes, so I am unsure if that has to do with the issue.

I have looked all over trying to find other people with this issue, but the last forum I found with the exact same issue as me was from 11 years ago, and I don't believe this is my issue: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2008-06-28/anchor-links-not-working

I have tried having the anchor set using both name and id, and the link shows it is connected, but the page doesn't move to the anchor when clicking the link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, why don't you think you have the same issue? Have you confirmed the id and name attributes appear in the rendered html?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that the id and name attributes are in the rendered html. The issue that was listed in the link had something to do with an HTML Purifier module, which as far as I know, I have not activated or installed. Unless it is something that is default, forgive me this is my first ever Drupal website.

Comment: I also tried both adding <a href hreflang name id> and unchecking the "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" option in the Restricted HTML section, but when I hit save the website has an error.

Comment: If there is no scrolling but the tags are correctly encoded in the HTML, this is most likely a CSS/JS issue, but it's very difficult to diagnose without access to the actual page.

Comment: The URL for the page I am having trouble with is https://h3doeshosting.com/services